# How can I print to stderr in C without using printf or puts or any function from their families?

Tags: c

Is there a C function to print to stderr without using printf or puts or any function from their families?

Comment: I believe your question is: "Can you output without using any output function from the C standard library?" That will be will be platform dependent, since you are prohibiting any other way of doing it. Might depend on exactly what you mean by stderr on whatever platform you are talking about as well.

Comment: What is your motivation? Is this an interview question? Is your system missing printf? Maybe you are trying to solve an X-Y-Problem.

Comment: @Jens `printf` can be one of the largest functions in the standard library, because of the complexity of parsing the format string.  It's not uncommon to want to avoid it in a memory constrained environment.

Comment: I remember a big step forward in my understanding of C, the C library, and the operating system underneath, when I figured out how the functions in `<stdio.h>` related to system calls like `open` and `write`.  So a pedagogical exercise exploring these distinctions, though perhaps artificial-looking, is not necessarily a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

Using plain standard C there's only the functions you mention that can write to `stdout`, `stderr`, and read from `stdin`.

However, those are modeled on the UNIX standard output, error and input file descriptors. So if you're on a system like Linux or macOS then you can use [the `write` system call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) to write to `STDERR_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` (defined in [the `<unistd.h>` header file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html)).

Windows have something similar of course, with [`GetStdHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) and [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile).

Answer (score 4):

Use the `write` system call:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char buf[] = "Hello, world!\n";
   write(2, buf, strnlen(buf,sizeof(buf)));
}
```

Comment: Almost. `buf[]` will include a terminating NUL and using `sizeof buf` is off-by-one, outputting the NUL character. strlen(buf) would be better, or subtracting 1.

Comment: @Jens: You are absolutely correct, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

Use `fwrite` from `stdio.h`, it writes data from array to a file:

```
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
```

The function allow you to specify the file. This can be `stderr` in your case:

```
char str[] = "This is a string";
fwrite(str, sizeof(char), strlen(str), stderr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard `fwrite()` function and specify `stderr` as the last argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t fwrite(const void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems,
              FILE *restrict stream);
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the `write` syscall on POSIX-compliant systems and specify `STDERR_FILENO` as the first argument:

```
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```